# Adding bind-mounts to the containers for running a task in concourse

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, concourse

I want to access the docker socket on the host where my worker runs while executing task.

When running a "regular" docker container I can just bind-mount the socket into the container. Can I some how do the same when specifying a task in concourse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes against Concourse's principle of workers being stateless. Tasks should not make any assumptions about the worker they're running on, i.e. that it has a Docker daemon running, or where the socket lives. I would recommend running Docker inside your task container instead.